# Access DataContext behind IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, iqueryable

Is it possible to access the DataContext object behind an IQueryable?

If so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DataContext is specific to LINQ to SQL, so presumably you're talking about LINQ to SQL queries? If so, there's no safe way to do this - you have to resort to a hack such as using reflection to retrieve the private "context" field of the underlying DataQuery object:

```
static DataContext GetContext (IQueryable q)
{
  if (!q.GetType().FullName.StartsWith ("System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1")) return null;
  var field = q.GetType().GetField ("context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
  if (field == null) return null;
  return field.GetValue (q) as DataContext;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned this is a hack, but it should not be recommended even as such. Accessing private members through reflection is not a good practice, and it will produce brittle code. Doing so also hides the dependency between the calling code and the DataContext class.

Comment: +1 as this can actually be used 'as a hack' to access the context when  someone returns IQueryable and then has full access to query away  : )

Comment: A small addition. System.Data.Linq.Table<> may also be behing IQueryable interface. Code:                                       string typeName = q.GetType().FullName;

            if (!typeName.StartsWith("System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1", StringComparison.Ordinal)
                && !typeName.StartsWith("System.Data.Linq.Table`1", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return null;
            }

Comment: could this be used to dynamically tell the IQueryable to use a different DataContext?

Comment: @nitewulf50 sure why not, just use the setter