# .Net EF Core 2.1 Get DbContext from IQueryable argument

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dbcontext

I have an IQueryable extension method:

```
public static void SomeExt<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DbContext context) {...}
```

and I would like to know if there is some way to get DbContext from query so that DbContext argument could be removed leaving only:

```
public static void SomeExt<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) {...}
```

I have tried something like this
[Access DataContext behind IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208439/access-datacontext-behind-iqueryable)
but its not working, getting zero fields.

Also there is way to get it from DbSet
[Can you get the DbContext from a DbSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710769/can-you-get-the-dbcontext-from-a-dbset)
*myDbSet.GetService<'ICurrentDbContext>().Context;*
but that's not what I need. I want to get it from Query?

This is the query:
***var q = context.Items.Where(a => a.StatusId = 1);***

***q.SomeExt(context);***
vs
***q.SomeExt();***

Comment: This won't work with just any IQueryable implementation so we have to rely on the underlying types. What is the value of `query.GetType().FullName` for the IQueryable you want to use this on?

Comment: For FullName of this Query type  (<T> is 'Item') I'm getting:
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[[EFCore.MyExtensions.Tests.Item, EFCore.MyExtensions.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"

Comment: This is a really peculiar thing to want to do, perhaps you could explain why you need this?

Comment: For BatchDelete as Extension on Query.

Comment: You had the exact same problem that I am currently facing!  So did you eventually settle on passing the context as a parameter, or did one of the solutions below work out for you?  I don't want to bundle the context in with the IQueryable, but I am also not super keen on a solution that could break every time EFCore is updated....

Comment: I have used the method GetDbContext(IQueryable query). Changes are not that often and you can make a test for this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found a way to do this

```
public static DbContext GetDbContext(IQueryable query)
{
    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    var queryCompiler = typeof(EntityQueryProvider).GetField("_queryCompiler", bindingFlags).GetValue(query.Provider);
    var queryContextFactory = queryCompiler.GetType().GetField("_queryContextFactory", bindingFlags).GetValue(queryCompiler);

    var dependencies = typeof(RelationalQueryContextFactory).GetProperty("Dependencies", bindingFlags).GetValue(queryContextFactory);
    var queryContextDependencies = typeof(DbContext).Assembly.GetType(typeof(QueryContextDependencies).FullName);
    var stateManagerProperty = queryContextDependencies.GetProperty("StateManager", bindingFlags | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(dependencies);
    var stateManager = (IStateManager)stateManagerProperty;

    return stateManager.Context;
}
```

For EFCore 3 instead of

```
.GetProperty("Dependencies", bindingFlags)
```

use

```
.GetField("_dependencies", bindingFlags)
```

Comment: Be careful! While this works, it relies on internal private properties that might change on every update of EFCore. Even a patch version might break this.

Comment: just did this on EF Core 6, it's "Dependencies"! lol

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else comes here and is trying to do this with EF Core 7 then the context is a private field of the InternalDbSet object which is created when you do a LINQ query. To get context from IQueryable do this:

```
FieldInfo fi = query.GetType().GetField("_context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
DbContext context = fi.GetValue(query) as DbContext;
```

Comment: `fi` returns `null` in EF Core 7. And when I put a breakpoint, I don't see `_context` in the debugger

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to implement ActiveRecord in Entity Framework. Many have tried... Best I can suggest is make your context.Items property something LINQ-like that bootlegs the context, e.g:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    QueryableWithContext<Item> Items {get => new QueryableWithContext<Item>(ItemsSet, this)}
    private DbSet<Item> ItemsSet {get;set;}
}

public class QueryableWithContext<T>
{
    public DbContext Context { get; }
    private IQueryable<T> inner;

    public QueryableWithContext(IQueryable<T> inner, DbContext context)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
        this.Context = context;
    }

    public QueryableWithContext<T> Where(Func<T,bool> predicate)
    {
        return new QueryableWithContext<T>(inner.Where(predicate) as IQueryable<T>, Context);
    }

    // plus lots of other LINQ-like expressions
}
```

Then your extension method is not on `IQueryable<T>` but on `QueryableWithContext<T>`, and can access the `Context` property.

Comment: Nice idea, but requires separate QueryableWithContext for each set, so not ideal.
I just might stick with sending Context as argument.

Comment: Yep I'd recommend that

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 public static DbContext GetDbContext(this IQueryable query)
    {
        var compilerField = typeof(EntityQueryProvider).GetField("_queryCompiler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var compiler = (QueryCompiler)compilerField.GetValue(query.Provider);

        var queryContextFactoryField = compiler.GetType().GetField("_queryContextFactory", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var queryContextFactory = (RelationalQueryContextFactory)queryContextFactoryField.GetValue(compiler);


        object stateManagerDynamic;

        var dependenciesProperty = typeof(RelationalQueryContextFactory).GetProperty("Dependencies", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (dependenciesProperty != null)
        {
            // EFCore 2.x
            var dependencies = dependenciesProperty.GetValue(queryContextFactory);

            var stateManagerField = typeof(DbContext).GetTypeFromAssembly_Core("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContextDependencies").GetProperty("StateManager", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            stateManagerDynamic = stateManagerField.GetValue(dependencies);
        }
        else
        {
            // EFCore 1.x
            var stateManagerField = typeof(QueryContextFactory).GetProperty("StateManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            stateManagerDynamic = stateManagerField.GetValue(queryContextFactory);
        }

        IStateManager stateManager = stateManagerDynamic as IStateManager;

        if (stateManager == null)
        {
            Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef<IStateManager> lazyStateManager = stateManagerDynamic as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef<IStateManager>;
            if (lazyStateManager != null)
            {
                stateManager = lazyStateManager.Value;
            }
        }

        if (stateManager == null)
        {
            stateManager = ((dynamic)stateManagerDynamic).Value;
        }


        return stateManager.Context;
    }
```