# Access foreign key properties from IQueryable<T> in Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a `IQueryable<T>` extension method and I would like to get the foreign keys of the navigation properties of `T`. I have figured out that I can get access to them through `IModel.FindEntityType(T).GetNavigations()`, the question is how to best get access to the `IModel` while keeping the method as simple as possible.

At the moment the method looks something like this:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TQuery> DoMagic<TQuery>(this IQueryable<TQuery> query, IModel model)
{
    var entity = model.FindEntityType(entityType);
    var navigationProperties = entity.GetNavigations();

    ...
}
```

I would love if I wouldn't need to pass `IModel` as an argument like this:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TQuery> DoMagic<TQuery>(this IQueryable<TQuery> query)
{
    var entity = Model.FindEntityType(entityType);
    var navigationProperties = entity.GetNavigations();

    ...
}
```

I have considered adding a `IServiceCollection` extension method and passing the `DbContext` and setting `IModel` as a static property to the `IQueryable<T>` extension method. The problem with that is that it is limiting me to one `DbContext`.

I have also looked into the option to add a extension method to `DbContextOptionsBuilder` but haven't really figured out best way to achieve what I want to do this way.

Maybe there is other ways to get access to the foreign keys? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

From the navigation properties I want to access the `ForeignKey`-property to know what property is used to resolve the navigation property. Something like:

```cs
navigationProperties.ToList().Select(x => x.ForeignKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting the navigation properties:

```
public static IQueryable<TQuery> DoMagic<TQuery>(this IQueryable<TQuery> query)
{
    var navigationProperties = typeof(TQuery).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.PropertyType != typeof(string)))
        .ToArray();

    ...
}
```

UPDATE:
Trying to get `DbContext` which has the `Model` property from `IQueryable` would result in some not pretty code, this link shows how it could be done:

[.Net EF Core 2.1 Get DbContext from IQueryable argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198376/net-ef-core-2-1-get-dbcontext-from-iqueryable-argument)

If you are using dependency injection, you could put the instance of DbContext into the container in the scope of the web request or the operation and inject it into the class with the `DoMagic` method.

Another way could to add the method to the descendant of `DbContext` class, then the model parametere would not be needed.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with that solution is that it doesn't give me the Foreign Keys, only the navigation propertie, I should probably have clarified that more.

Comment: Updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: Yeah, I passed by that question a couple of times and yes, some not pretty code I agree with  Just wanted to see if there was some solution that I'm missing. I guess I just need to accept that there is no perfect solution and pick one of the lesser evils! Thanks!